# VEGA Sunburst highlight current node and parent path

Tags: vega

I am trying to highlight node and all linked parents when we hover with a mouse.

So I ask VEGA : " is my datum.currentNode of my arc mark a parent of my currently hovered node ?"

```
{
  "name": "hoveredArcDetail",
  
  "on": [
    {"trigger": "hoveredArcIn", "toggle": "hoveredArcIn"},
    {"trigger": "hoveredText", "toggle": "hoveredText"}
  ],
  "transform": [
    {"type": "flatten", "fields": ["myTreeAncestorList"]},
    {
      "type": "formula",
      "expr": "datum.myTreeAncestorList.currentNodeAndAncestors",
      "as": "nodeToCheckIfParentOfCurrentNode"
    }
  ]
},

"fillOpacity": [
        {
          "test": "indata('hoveredTextDetail','nodeToCheckIfParentOfCurrentNode',datum.currentNodeAndAncestors)||indata('hoveredArcDetail','nodeToCheckIfParentOfCurrentNode',datum.currentNodeAndAncestors)",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "test": "((isHoveredOnArc==true)||(isHoveredOnText==true))&&!indata('hoveredArcDetail','nodeToCheckIfParentOfCurrentNode',datum.currentNodeAndAncestors)",
          "value": 0.5
        }
      ]
```

Yet the problem is that, when my toggle trigger empties my data when we don't hoover, my transform flatten and formula throws me an error ( as expected ) saying that we cant find such data.

Does anyone have an idea to handle this error ? Thank you !

Full spec is available here
https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/ab2b39162b7c3240aa2cbe84d42aa6fb/spec.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved by setting interactivity for text mark as false:

```
{
  "type": "text",
  "from": {
    "data": "nodeLabels"

  },
  "interactive":false
```